# base64 encoded image displays fine in IE/Edge but not in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: html, base64

So I randomly grabbed 5 jpg images off images.google.com "drivers licenses"  Then I base 64 encode all of them using org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 library and spit them out on an html webpage.  They all look great except for this one image.  It displays fine in IE/Edge but not in Chrome/Firefox.

Any ideas?  Is it something weird with the libary I'm using or something weird with the jpg image itself?

Here's a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/ccw6vu81/

```
<body>lotsof64bitEncodedImage</body>
```

I would post a stacksnippet but awhile back when SO got all political and had rainbows all over their site I blocked all images from them so it's possible I cannot find the link to create the stack snippet because of that...Not that I'm opposed to LGBT and rainbows it's just that since I suffer from ophthalmic migraines I find rainbows in general induce a sort of panic attack that I find unpleasant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay mystery solved.  Apparently when I downloaded all the sample images I didn't pay close enough attention to the types.  One of the files was a .png not a .jpg.  So this particular image is a png where all the rest were jpg.  Which wouldn't necessarily be a problem however the intermediary tool I'm using to import these files before I then convert them to base64 leaves JPGs alone but converts png files to tiff files.  So then I base64 encode the tiff files and try and display them in web pages which apparently works in IE/Edge but not in Chrome/FF.  The actual base64 encoding of a png works in all browsers unfortunately this intermediary tool doesn't leave pngs as pngs.  I confirmed this by downloading a .tif file from http://www.nightprogrammer.org/wp-uploads/2013/02/multipage_tiff_example.tif converting it to base64 and then embedding it in an  tag.  It works in Edge/IE but not in FF/Chrome.  So apparently IE/Edge have an engine that can convert tif images but Chrome and FF don't.